# PyQt5 - try to build a gui with dynamic content

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, signals, pyqt5

I would like to realize a gui to show fathers and their children. If you click on a child, it will be father and his children will fill the lables on the screen.

The family tree is an object "familytree". The Gui uses customized pyqt-classes. You could see below the initial screen.
I'm stuck with the evaluation of the signal.

```
  def kinderInitialisieren(self):
    # kinder
    self.kinderName = [0 for kind in range(10)]
    self.kinderNr = [0 for kind in range(10)]

    for kind in range(10):
        kinderLabel = TextFeld("Kind: ")
        self.gestaltung.addWidget(kinderLabel, 1 + kind , 0)
        self.kinderName[kind] = ButtonFeelsLikeLabel("Name")
        self.gestaltung.addWidget(self.kinderName[kind], 1 + kind, 1)
        self.kinderName[kind].pressed.connect( lambda n=kind: self.welcherKnopfGedrueckt(n))
```

Lambda-function delivers the index of the clicked button (I realized the names of children as buttons). But this index is like caged in the namespace of the class/function. For getting the children of person/button no.1 I've to access the object "family tree". How to break the namespace-prison?

GUI Family tree

[image]

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is very hard to understand. What do you mean by "caged in the namespace"? What is "object 'family tree'"?

Comment: I try to make it more transparent. There a 2 objects: the Gui-object and the object "family tree". Gui delivers the structure. This structure is filled by content from the object "familiy tree". For example the white rectangles on the user interface are buttons, defined as attributes in the object "Gui". The names on the buttons are delivered by the object "family tree". If you click on one of the buttons, the names on the button should change. The new names will delivered by the "family tree". Signal emitted by the click return index of the button, but this information is a local variable.

Comment: Descriptions of code and how it works are the wrong way to write questions. Always include all the relevant code in the question itself. Ideally, this should be a [mcve].

Comment: I could solve the riddle. The instances of the classes where initialized separatly. If I initialized the object with the content in the instance of the gui everything runs. Thanks to an example of eyllanesc in an answer to another question.